# enable/disable button using case statement

Tags: javascript, asp.net

> Hello, need help pleaseI already tried adding a break on both end of condition ..I Have 5 Textboxes, 1 Button and a Javascript for their function. What i want to do is this..

CASE 1: When the value of Stat variable is "N", The program must require an input on Area, Capital and Code for the ADD button to enable else it will disable.

CASE 2 When the value of Stat variable is "R", The program must require an input on Area, Gross and Code textboxes for the ADD button to enable else it will disable. I have tried to code it this way.. But it didn't work.

```
function SetButtonStatus() {

        var Stat = document.getElementById('<%=_oTextBoxNRC.ClientID%>').value;
        var Area = document.getElementById('<%=_oTextBoxArea.ClientID%>').value;
        var Capital = document.getElementById('<%=_oTextBoxCapital.ClientID%>').value;
        var Code = document.getElementById('<%= _oTextboxBusLineCode.ClientID%>').value;
        var Gross = document.getElementById('<%=_oTextBoxGrossRec.ClientID%>').value;
        //Change these conditions as your requirement

        switch (Stat) {

            case 'N':

                if (parseFloat(Area) >= 1 && parseFloat(Capital) >= 1 && Code.length >= 1)
                    document.getElementById('<%=_oButtonAdd.ClientID%>').disabled = false;
                else
                    document.getElementById('<%=_oButtonAdd.ClientID%>').disabled = true;
                break;
            case 'R':

                if (parseFloat(Area) >= 1 && parseFloat(Gross) >= 1 && Code.length >= 1)
                    document.getElementById('<%=_oButtonAdd.ClientID%>').disabled = false;
                else
                    document.getElementById('<%=_oButtonAdd.ClientID%>').disabled = true;
                break;
        }

    }
```

Comment: when `Stat == 'N'` both cases will run, because case statements fall through without a `break`

Comment: you need `break` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: I already tried adding a break on both end of condition , but still nothing happened.

Comment: I do not understand what your question is. What is the issue?

Comment: Good day Sir..
What i want to do is this...
 CASE 1: When the value of Stat variable is "N", The program must require an input on Area, Capital and Code for the ADD button to enable else it will disable.

 CASE 2 When the value of Stat variable is "R", The program must require an input on Area, Gross and Code textboxes for the ADD button to enable else it will disable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setAttribute` and `removeAttribute` like this:

```
 if (parseFloat(Area) >= 1 && parseFloat(Capital) >= 1 && Code.length >= 1)
 {
     document.getElementById('<%=_oButtonAdd.ClientID%>')
         .setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
 }
 else
 {
     document.getElementById('<%=_oButtonAdd.ClientID%>')
         .removeAttribute('disabled');
 }
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion sir, but still did't work :(

Comment: @louiejayaviles Not sure what you mean. It works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/54XB2/808/) so why would it not work for  you. What is your exact javascript code when you view it in browser developer tools?